# Where does Ichi save game progress?

Tags: ichi

In what location on the filesystem does [Ichi](http://www.desura.com/games/ichi/) store your progress through the game when you save in game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Windows

On Windows, Ichi doesn't store saved game state in the filesytem directly, but stores it in a Registry key. To access it:

1. Open the Start Menu.
2. In the "Search programs and files" box, type `regedt32`.
3. Open the `regedt32.exe` program in the search results that appear.

Once opened, navigate to:

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER → Software → Stolen Couch Games → Ichi

There, you'll see a key named something like `SaveDataLite_h3434896000` that contains the save data.

### Mac

On Mac purchased through the Mac App Store, the save data is found at:

> ~/Library/Containers/com.stolencouchgames.ichidesktop/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.stolencouchgames.ichidesktop.savedState/

### Linux

> ~/.config/unity3d/Stolen Couch Games/Ichi/